# Nifi extract content from ExecuteSQL output

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-nifi, vertica

I am trying to fetch the DDL from Oracle, and then convert the DDL into syntax appropriate for Vertica database. My ExecuteSQL processor SQL query is:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','${table_name}','${owner}') as t_ddl from dual
```

I am getting the following output in AVRO format:

```
Objavro.schemaú{"type":"record","name":"NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record","namespace":"any.data","fields":[{"name":"T_DDL","type":["null","string"]}]}avro.codecnull­¶½``¼�÷KGÙ‡LÞoCäÞ
  CREATE TABLE "VDBA"."CUSTOMERS" 
   (    "CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(50), 
    "ITEMS_CNT" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "TSTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ­¶½``¼�÷KGÙ‡LÞoC
```

From this output, I only need the following text:

```
CREATE TABLE VDBA.CUSTOMERS 
   (CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
    CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    CITY VARCHAR2(50), 
    ITEMS_CNT NUMBER(5,0), 
    TSTAMP TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
   )
```

I am unable to understand how to proceed next. Will ReplaceText processor work here? Please give me some pointers to move ahead.

Thanks & Regards,
Bishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `ConvertAvroToJSON` processor and then manipulating or extracting the JSON from there.

Comment: Thank you ! I achieved the intended result. After `ConvertAvroToJSON`, I have applied a few `ReplaceText` to get the desired words, then a `ExtractText` to store the sql in an attribute, and finally a `ExecuteSQL` to use the attribute and create the table.

Answer (score 3):

As of NiFi 1.8.0, you can use ExecuteSQLRecord instead of ExecuteSQL, then you don't need a conversion processor afterwards. Then you can use either CSVRecordSetWriter (configured to not output the header or quote strings) or a FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter with the text `${T_DDL}` to output the contents of the single field containing the DDL statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I will try this to shorten the flow.